# Conditional count per day from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have a dataset with a reading (Tank Level) every minute from a piece of equipment and want to create a new dataset (dataframe) with a count of the number of samples per day and the number of readings above a set value.

```
        Noxious Tank Level.MIN  Noxious Tank Level.MAX           Date_Time
0                         9.32                    9.33 2019-12-31 05:01:00
1                         9.32                    9.34 2019-12-31 05:02:00
2                         9.32                    9.35 2019-12-31 05:03:00
3                         9.31                    9.35 2019-12-31 05:04:00
4                         9.31                    9.35 2019-12-31 05:05:00
...                        ...                     ...                 ...
528175                    2.98                    3.01 2020-12-31 23:56:00
528176                    2.98                    3.02 2020-12-31 23:57:00
528177                    2.98                    3.01 2020-12-31 23:58:00
528178                    2.98                    3.02 2020-12-31 23:59:00
528179                    2.98                    2.99 2021-01-01 00:00:00
```

Using a lamdba function I can see whether each value is an overflow (Tank Level > setpoint) - I have also indexed the dataframe by Date_Time:

`df['Overflow'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if x['Noxious Tank Level.MIN'] > 89 else False , axis=1)`

```
                     Noxious Tank Level.MIN  Noxious Tank Level.MAX  Overflow
Date_Time                                                                    
2019-12-31 05:01:00                    9.32                    9.33     False
2019-12-31 05:02:00                    9.32                    9.34     False
2019-12-31 05:03:00                    9.32                    9.35     False
2019-12-31 05:04:00                    9.31                    9.35     False
2019-12-31 05:05:00                    9.31                    9.35     False
...                                     ...                     ...       ...
2020-12-31 23:56:00                    2.98                    3.01     False
2020-12-31 23:57:00                    2.98                    3.02     False
2020-12-31 23:58:00                    2.98                    3.01     False
2020-12-31 23:59:00                    2.98                    3.02     False
2021-01-01 00:00:00                    2.98                    2.99     False
```

Now I want to count the number of samples per day and the number of 'True' values in the `Overflow` column to work out what fraction per day is in Overflow

I get the feeling that `resample` or `groupby` will be the way to go but I can't  figure out how to create a new dataset with just these counts and include the *conditional* count from the `Overflow` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use:

```
df['Overflow'] = df['Noxious Tank Level.MIN'] > 89
```

And then for count `True`s use `sum` nad for count values use `size` per days/ dates:

```
df1 = df.resample('d')['Overflow'].agg(['sum','size'])
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Overflow'].agg(['sum','size'])
```

Or:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.date)['Overflow'].agg(['sum','size'])
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  As always with python / pandas it's think of the simplest way to do it and that will be the answer.  Does exactly what I needed - it was the `.agg` part that I was missing.